# How can I use for loops to figure out how to solve this?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j3Ne.png)5

I have to use a for loop to code this. I have tried many times but it never works.

```
enter code here
num_of_times = 5
for x in range(1, num_of_times, 5):
 for y in range(5, i+5):
  print(y, end= '')
 print('')
```

Comment: please post what you tried.

Comment: you need to provide your attempt.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```py
lst = []

for i in range(1, 5):
    lst.append(i * 5)
    print(*lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to print multiple of 5. That could be achieved with two nested for loops:

```
max = 5
for i in range(max):
    line = ''
    for j in range(i+1):
        line += str(5 * (j+1)) + ' '
    print(line)
```

The first loop goes from 0 to `max-1` and stores the index in `i` ; the second loop goes from 0 to `i+1` and stores the index in `j`.
Then, the result of `5 * (j+1)` is added to a variable called `line` printed at the end of the j-loop.
Feel free to follow the loops and the value of each variable at every step with a paper and a pen, that should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range (1, i+1):
        print(j*5, end = ' ')
    print('')
```

Comment: `a+1` should be `i+1`